# Type inference inconsistency

Tags: ida, decompilation, ghidra, jeb

I'm testing several decompilers against the following `C` code

```
static int bar(int i) {
    return ++i;
}

static int apply(int (*fun)(int), int i) {
    return i % fun(i);
}

static int foo(int (*app)(int (*fun)(int), int), int i)  {
    return i / app(bar, i);
}

int main() {
    return foo(apply, 7);
}
```

which is compiled by just `clang test.c`.

```
; main
0x0         push rbp
0x1         mov rbp, rsp
0x4         sub rsp, 0x10
0x8         mov dword ptr [rbp-0x4], 0x0
0xf         mov rdi, @apply
0x19        mov esi, 0x7
0x1e        call foo
0x23        add rsp, 0x10
0x27        pop rbp
0x28        ret

; foo
0x30        push rbp
0x31        mov rbp, rsp
0x34        sub rsp, 0x20
0x38        mov [rbp-0x8], rdi
0x3c        mov [rbp-0xc], esi
0x3f        mov eax, [rbp-0xc]
0x42        mov rcx, [rbp-0x8]
0x46        mov esi, [rbp-0xc]
0x49        mov rdi, @bar
0x53        mov [rbp-0x10], eax
0x56        call rcx
0x58        mov edx, [rbp-0x10]
0x5b        mov [rbp-0x14], eax
0x5e        mov eax, edx
0x60        cdq
0x61        mov esi, [rbp-0x14]
0x64        idiv esi
0x66        add rsp, 0x20
0x6a        pop rbp
0x6b        ret
```

I was aware of some limits in argument/parameter detection (from the response to [another question](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/22634/struct-reconstruction-in-decompilers)). But each decompiler seems, in one way or another, have inconsistency in the type system of its decompiled language (I think they all try to decompile to `C` or pseudo-`C`).

`IDA v.7.4.191122` (evaluation version) gives:

```
int __cdecl main(int argc, const char **argv, const char **envp)
{
  return foo(apply, 7LL, envp);
}

__int64 __fastcall foo(int (__fastcall *a1)(__int64 (__fastcall *)(), _QWORD), unsigned int a2)
{
  return (unsigned int)((int)a2 / a1(bar, a2));
}
```

I don't show results of `bar` and `apply` because there was already an inconsistency here: IDA detects that `foo` is called with 3 arguments in `main`, but then it concludes that `foo` has actually 2 parameters.

Next, `Ghidra v9.1.build.2019-oct-23`:

```
void main(void)
{
  foo(apply,7);
  return;
}

ulong foo(code *param_1,uint param_2,undefined8 param_3)
{
  int iVar1;

  iVar1 = (*param_1)(bar,(ulong)param_2,param_3,param_1);
  return (long)(int)param_2 / (long)iVar1 & 0xffffffff;
}
```

which has an opposite opinion: `foo` is called in `main` with 2 arguments, but in its definition `foo` has 3 parameters.

`JEB v.3.8.0.201912242244` (evaluation version):

```
unsigned long main() {
  return foo(&apply, 7L);
}

unsigned long foo(unsigned long param0) {
  unsigned int v0 = v1;
  param0();
  return (unsigned long)(v0 / ((unsigned int)v2));
}
```

which gives a perfect result for `main`, but it then claims that `foo` is a function of just 1 parameters (and while it shows `param0()`, it keeps `param0` as `unsigned long`).

Actually, the decompilation results are not correct (which is somehow understandable), but they are even inconsistent. Do I miss some configuration?

Comment: `IDA` results look pretty good. I believe that the signature of `main` comes from any kind of `FLIRT` or other function recognitions - It detects that the function is `main`, and therefore gives it the default `main` signature. it looks like `foo` disassembled well. You can configure yourself the signature by pressing `y` on the function call. You must understand that the whole process is very heuristic, and this info does not appear anywhere in the binary.

Comment: Thank you. I understand that the decompilation currently bases on heuristics so it gives sometimes unattended results, but I supposed that it should be consistent.

Comment: I saw it several times in IDA, that it creates a good signature for a function but sometimes calls it with extra/missing parameters. I believe it's a bug, rather than something configurable.

Comment: Thank again. Could you please pick your comments as response so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IDA` results look pretty good. I believe that the signature of `main` comes from any kind of `FLIRT` or other function recognitions - It detects that the function is `main`, and therefore gives it the default main signature. it looks like `foo` disassembled well. You can configure yourself the signature by pressing `y` on the function call. You must understand that the whole process is very heuristic, and this info does not appear anywhere in the binary.

I saw it several times in `IDA`, that it creates a good signature for a function but sometimes calls it with extra/missing parameters. I believe it's a bug, rather than something configurable.