# Methods for preventing IDA decompiler

Tags: ida, c, hexrays, decompile

I want to write a C function, such that `hex-rays` decompiler will fail on it. I want to do it for study purposes, and not for an actual anti-reversing method. Do you have any recommendations/approaches how can I write such a function, that will compile with `gcc` or similar compiler, but won't be decompilable by `hex-rays`?

**EDIT:** 
My goal is to make the code disassemblable, but not decompilable. I'm not looking for obfuscators that will hide the code completely, but a way to make IDA not to be able to decompile. for example, by somehow messing with the stack pointer.

Comment: There's a concept called obfuscation. That's what you're looking for. Try giving the tag by the name name a peek: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/obfuscation

Comment: Thanks, my question wasn't very clear, but I edited it now. Anyways I will go through your link and maybe find something relevant.

Comment: why are you be interested specifically in preventing decompilation and not disassembly? for the record, though, obfuscated code _is_ disassembleable, just not to anything too intelligible.

Comment: Does the example in [my question](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/22827/type-inference-inconsistency) count? Or you want another example? I observe that IDA does not care much in detecting function types.

Comment: @NirIzr I think much effort have focused on anti-disassembly. While it's correct that anti-disassembly will help anti-decompilation, they are not the same.

Comment: @TaThanhDinh I am looking for examples that are not decompilable - when IDA gives an error.

Comment: @TaThanhDinh. I'd say obfuscation is more of as much anti-decompilation as it gets. The only exception I can think of is utilizing decompiler bugs.

Comment: @macr0controller IDA cannot decompile if it cannot detect a piece of asm code as a function. Lots of trick have exploited this fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check "[graceful failures](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/manual/failures.shtml#grace)" for some common problems that can prevent decompilation and try to induce them deliberately. However, most of them can be worked around with a bit of effort so don’t expect them to stop a motivated person.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @igor says about algorithm failures of IDA. Beside, I think you can use a function which is not type-able in the type system of the decompilation target language of IDA (I believe it's a subset of C), e.g.

```
int foo(void *f, int i) {
    return ((int (*)(void*, int))(f))(foo, i);
}

clang -c test.c
```

then IDA decompilers gives something likes

```
__int64 __fastcall foo(__int64 (__fastcall *a1)(__int64 (__fastcall *)(), _QWORD), unsigned int a2)
{
  return a1(foo, a2);
}
```

which is obviously not correct: `foo` is recognized simultaneously as a function of two params and one param.